# NullPointerException by accessing Object in JButton Array

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

So I created a little snake game.
In my constructor I call the "CreateSnake" function, which creates a Snake with JButtons.

```
    private void createSnake()
    {
        snakeButtonx[0] = 100; //Sets the starter position of the snake
        snakeButtony[0] = 150;
        JButton tempButton; //temporary Button for adding button to the Snake

        // Initially the snake has length of 5
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeSnake; i++) 
        {
            snakeButton[i] = new JButton("" + i);
            snakeButton[i].setEnabled(false); // Disable the buttons so you cant click it

            tempButton = snakeButton[i];
            Surface.addSnake(tempButton, i);
            snakeButton[i].setBounds(snakeButtonx[i], snakeButtony[i], 10, 10);
            snakeButtonx[i + 1] = snakeButtonx[i] - 10;
            snakeButtony[i + 1] = snakeButtony[i];
        }
    }
```

Then I have a move function, which is called every 100 milliseconds via a thread

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void move() 
{
    snakeButtonx[0] += directionx; //Set the position of the head of the snake
    snakeButtony[0] += directiony;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeSnake; i++)
    {
        snakeButtonPos[i] = snakeButton[i].getLocation(); //Fills the snakeButtonPos integer with the positions of every Button
    }

    snakeButton[0].setBounds(snakeButtonx[0], snakeButtony[0], 10, 10);

    for (int i = 1; i < sizeSnake; i++) 
    {
        snakeButton[i].setLocation(snakeButtonPos[i - 1]);
    }
    show();
}
```

So. Till here, it works fine. But whenever I want to add a sixth JButton to my JButton array, I get a nullpointer exception in my move methode.

```
private void Grow()
{
    JButton tempButton = new JButton(); 
    int newIndex = sizeSnake + 1;

    // Add the new Button to the Button Array
    snakeButton[newIndex] = new JButton();
    snakeButton[newIndex].setEnabled(false);

    tempButton = snakeButton[newIndex];
    Surface.addSnake(tempButton, newIndex);

    // Position is irrelevant, cause the position will be fixed at the next call of move()
    snakeButton[newIndex].setBounds(200, 300, 10, 10);

    sizeSnake = sizeSnake + 1;
}
```

The sixth JButton is in the Jbutton array while Im in my `Grow()` function. But by the next call of `move()`, there isnt a JButton with the index 6 anymore.

Why do I get a NullPointerException? Where is the mistake?

**EDIT:** The error occurs on this line after the sixth loop in my move() function: `snakeButtonPos[i] = snakeButton[i].getLocation();`

And the exact exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Snake.move(Snake.java:92)
    at Snake.run(Snake.java:217)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT2**: I call move and Grow here in my Thread

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true)
    {
        CheckPosition(); //CheckPosition includes Grow() if the snake intersects with an object
        move();

        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get exceptions, ALWAYS show us the exception. Please include it in your post, it has important information. Also please tell us which line the exception occurs in (line number won't help us much)

Comment: Yep, the most important bit of information for NPE is the line that throws it. Please indicate for us which line this is. Also, an unrelated recommendation that you'll want to get rid of `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` and get rid of all deprecated calls. They're dangerous.

Comment: Like I guessed: `snakeButton[i]` is `null`, probably for `i=5`. Is it possible that you increased `sizeSnake` but didn't add the button to the array? Can you also show the snippet where you call `Grow()` and then `move()`?

Comment: Time to do some debugging. What is `i` when the NPE is thrown? Why is `snakeButton[i]` null for that value of `i`? If you search back through your code, there's a good chance that you'll find the problem. Note that we'd all be in a better position to help if you could condense your code into an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a minimal compilable runnable program that reproduces your problem for us. No, this is not easy to do, but is often worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Grow()`, try changing `int newIndex = sizeSnake + 1;` to `int newIndex = sizeSnake;`. Since your `for` loops all go until `i < sizeSnake`, that means the last `JButton` is actually the one at `snakeButton[sizeSnake - 1]`, not the one at `snakeButton[sizeSnake]`.

Comment: Dammit, you beat me to it

Comment: @Sentry: but you both had sharp eyes and good instincts. one up to each.

Answer (score 2):

Since some code is missing, a shot in the dark:

```
private void Grow()
{
    JButton tempButton = new JButton(); 
    int newIndex = sizeSnake + 1;

    // Add the new Button to the Button Array
    snakeButton[newIndex] = new JButton();
    snakeButton[newIndex].setEnabled(false);

    ...
}
```

Say `sizeSnake` is 5, then `newIndex` is set to 6, so your `snakeButton` array looks like this afterwards:

```
[button, button, button, button, button, null, button, null, ...]
```

Because index 6 is the seventh element. The `newIndex` is unnecessary.

The `move()` method should be

```
private void Grow()
{
    JButton tempButton = new JButton(); 

    // Add the new Button to the Button Array
    snakeButton[sizeSnake] = new JButton();
    snakeButton[sizeSnake].setEnabled(false);

    tempButton = snakeButton[sizeSnake];
    Surface.addSnake(tempButton, sizeSnake);

    // Position is irrelevant, cause the position will be fixed at the next call of move()
    snakeButton[sizeSnake].setBounds(200, 300, 10, 10);

    sizeSnake = sizeSnake + 1;
}
```